# localizedStringWithFormat is showing space for NSNumber object in French language

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I am supporting few languages in my project including French.

```
self.lblMax.text=[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.arrValues.lastObject floatValue]],self.strUnit];
```

In above code line, **arrValues** is having list of `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:val]` objects. I am taking lastObject as the maximum number and appending its unit through `localizedStringWithFormat` method of `NSString`.

Let say, lastobject of arrValues array is 24000 So I am getting value "24 000ms" (with space) instead of normal "24000ms"

Since I had already set french language and France region both.

Sometimes It was showing comma "24,000ms" in UILabel but the actual value was 24000 only. I used `stringByReplacingOccurence` method to remove comma.

Kindly assist and correct me If I am doing something wrong for french localization.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Showing the number 24000 as `24 000` is perfectly normal in some locales, including France. Some locales show it as `24,000`. Some show it as `24.000`. Some may show it other ways. There is nothing wrong with what you are seeing.

You may wish to consider using `NSNumberFormatter` to format numbers.

If your app is only supporting iOS 10 and later, you should look into using `NSMeasurement` and `NSMeasurementFormatter` instead of creating your own format string to ensure your number and units are really shown properly for a given locale.

Comment: Yes, coming space in numbers (24 000) is normal for few locales but in French language decimal numbers shows as comma seperated (24,000) So in my app for some decimal value (float) it shows 24,000 and for some number in which there is no any decimal point it shows space like 24 000. In my case 24000 is added in array by [NSNumber numberWithFloat:val] where val is a float value. I debugged it, While assigning through localised string to UILabel its inserting space.

Comment: Under iOS and OS X, when a number is formatted for the locale `fr_FR`, the number 24000 is formatted as `24 000` (with a space), not with a comma. The comma is used for the fraction, not the grouping. What you are seeing is correct behavior.